# How do I use bookmarks sync?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, firefox, couchdb

I'm using 11.04 Natty here, and have enabled bookmarks sync in the Ubuntu One configuration on my Desktop.

I have also done the same on my laptop.

However, my bookmarks are not syncing. I figured there'd probably be a little config utility for this, or a 'synchronize now!' button, but I've not found anything of the sort. So, my basic question is this:

How do I USE the bookmarks sync?

Edit: Yes, I have bindwood installed and enabled on both computers. Both computers also successfully synchronize files. However, bookmarks are not synchronizing.

Comment: Is one of them Firefox 5? Because it doesn't yet work on Firefox 5.

Comment: I've also had problems with Ubutu One's bookmark sync. I use Firefox's own sync instead (it can also sync other things). You can reach it in Settings under Sync.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the ubuntu one control panel in the services tab you will find an option install bookmarks sync.

I for one don't use this feature in ubuntu one because firefox also has native bookmark, configuration and password sync build in since 4.0.

Comment: I have already done that. Bookmark sync is enabled in the Ubuntu One control panel on both computers, and the plugin is installed and enabled on both.

Answer (score 1):

Tynach,

What version of Firefox are you on?

I'm on Natty too and the default installed (as far as I am aware) Firefox browser is V6.

When I go to Firefox/ Tools/ Add-ons/ Extensions to add Bindwood it says Bindwood 1.99.0 is incompatible with Firefox 6 and has been disabled.

So if you are using Firefox 6 it looks like it is not going to work until some update to fix this comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Xmarks addon. It support Firefox 8, Chrome, Internet Explorer 9 & Safari 5.

You can even access your bookmarks through website.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/#detail-relnotes
http://www.xmarks.com/